# how to count according to my result

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

how to count my current record how much time fade , trend and none iam  using below logic but its show me wrong result

```
  <td  ng-if="row.issue_type =='None'" ng-repeat="row in item.outdoor_tracking">{{$index }}</td>  
  <td  ng-if="row.issue_type =='Fade'" ng-repeat="row in item.outdoor_tracking">{{$index }}</td>   
  <td  ng-if="row.issue_type =='Trend'"ng-repeat="row in item.outdoor_tracking">{{$index }}</td>
```

[image]

Comment: There isn't enough information here to even begin to understand what your problem might be.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: i want show total count how much time  trend , fade , None  record are in below list

Comment: trend is 3 time in list,  but its show 5 time

Comment: @Claies check picture in picture show,  trend is 3 time, fade/Trend is 1 ,  None is 1 time in list

Comment: I can clearly see the screenshots, but screenshots **are not a [mcve]**.  You ***must show code*** if you want troubleshooting help, and the 3 `td` elements you provided here are not enough code to be anything useful.

Comment: if you don't have solution then sit down.

Comment: this is simple . i have array. i want to show  count of trend , fade and none.

Comment: Again, **show your code**.  As it stands now, you are expecting, at best, for people to write their own code to present to you as an answer, and at worst, to just make random guesses about what your code might look like.  This is much less likely to be helpful to you, and definitely not likely to help others in the future.  Please read [ask].  To put this another way, I don't have a solution, because you presented a 100 piece puzzle and gave us 4 pieces to solve it with.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understandings from your comments, I think this will work out for you

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in item.outdoor_tracking">
    <td ng-if="row.issue_type =='None'">{{$index }}</td>
    <td ng-if="row.issue_type =='Fade'">{{$index }}</td>
    <td ng-if="row.issue_type =='Trend'">{{$index }}</td>
</tr>
```

Happy Coding:)